# exercise of information-based approximation

Tags: approximation, computational-complexity

Let $1 \leq \alpha\leq2$. Find an example of a normed space $G$ and a set $A \subset G$ such that $d(A)=\alpha r(A)$. $($Where $r(A),d(A)$ are the Chebyshev radius and diameter$)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the information. I am new in this page and I didn't know well how it works… I am also new in mathematics studies and I am not able to give the example required in the exercise, maybe I don't understand the concepts correctly.